# git clone segmentation fault 8237

Tags: macos, git

Since shortly I have a problem with my git. The repo's I already have on my computer still works so I can still push and pull, etc ... But when I want to clone a new repo I always get things like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout.git
Cloning into 'PureLayout'...
remote: Counting objects: 1371, done.
remote: Total 1371 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1371
Receiving objects: 100% (1371/1371), 911.22 KiB | 983.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (911/911), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
[1]    8237 segmentation fault  git clone https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout.git
```

I'm running osx 10.11.5 and running git version 2.8.1

Comment: how can I verify that?

Comment: which git gives me /usr/local/bin/git and git --version gives me 2.8.1